# Users cannot update information in MySQL database using PHP form

Tags: php, mysql

I cannot figure out why my Update.php form is not updating the users information on my database even though I am getting a successfully updated message. I've tried every suggestion that I've found, but nothing has worked.

Here is my code:

**update.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

include_once 'dbconnect.php';

//set validation error flag as false
$error = false;

//check if form is submitted
if (isset($_POST['update'])) {
    $ident = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['id']);
    $name = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['name']);
    $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['email']);
    //$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['password']);
    //$cpassword = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['cpassword']);
    $dob = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['dob']);
    $phone = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['phone']);
    $gender = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['gendr']);
    $address = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['adrs']);
    $addresstwo = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['adrs_line']);
    $city = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['city']);
    $province = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['province']);
    $country = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['country']);
    $postal = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['zip']);
    $facebook = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['fbcdn']);
    $memberType = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['mtype']);

    //name can contain only alpha characters and space
    /*if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]+$/",$name)) {
        $error = true;
        $name_error = "Name must contain only alphabets and space";
    }
    if(!filter_var($email,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $error = true;
        $email_error = "Please Enter Valid Email ID";
    }
    if(strlen($password) < 6) {
        $error = true;
        $password_error = "Password must be minimum of 6 characters";
    }
    if($password != $cpassword) {
        $error = true;
        $cpassword_error = "Password and Confirm Password doesn't match";
    }
    if (!$error) {
        if(mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users(id,name,email,dob,phone,gender,address,addresstwo,city,province,country,postal,facebook,accountType) SET('" . $name . "', '" . $email . "', '" . $dob . "', '".$phone."', '".$gender."', '".$address."', '".$addresstwo."', '".$city."', '".$province."', '".$country."', '".$postal."', '".$facebook."', '".$memberType."')"."WHERE id = $ident")) {
            $successmsg = "Successfully Updated";
        } else {
            $errormsg = "Error in updating...Please try again later!";
        }
    }*/
     if($sql = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET name='$name', accountType='$memberType', email='$email', address='$address', addresstwo='$addresstwo', city='$city', province='$province', country='$country', postal='$postal', phone='$phone', dob='$dob', gender='$gender', facebook='$facebook' WHERE id='$ident'"));

            mysqli_query($sql,$con);
            echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Update my info Script</title>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" name="viewport" >
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" />
    <style type="text/css">input:invalid+span.validity:after {
    content: 'Invalid';
    text-align:center;
    color:#ff0000;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:800;
    padding-left: 5px;
}

input:valid+span.validity:after {
    content: 'Valid';
    text-align:center;
    color:green;
    font-size:20px;
    font-weight:800;
    padding-left: 5px;
}</style>
</head>
<body style="background-image:url(http://vampnerdlord.com/webBranding/sites/images/acoounts/starfield.png)!important;background-repeat: repeat!important;">

<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation" style="background:url(http://vampnerdlord.com/webBranding/sites/images/acoounts/wood4.png)!important;background-repeat: repeat-x!important;">
    <div class="container-fluid" style="background-image:url(http://vampnerdlord.com/webBranding/sites/images/acoounts/wood4.png)!important;background-repeat: repeat-x!important;">
        <div class="navbar-header" style="background-image:url(http://vampnerdlord.com/webBranding/sites/images/acoounts/wood4.png)!important;background-repeat: repeat-x!important;">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar1">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <img height=40px valign=top src="//vampnerdlord.com/webBranding/sites/images/acoounts/vnl_webaccount_branding_logo_white_shadowed.png" title="test" />
        </div>
        <!-- menu items -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbar1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right" style="color:white">
                <?php if (isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) { ?>
                <li><p class="navbar-text"  style="color:white">Signed in as <?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name']; ?></p></li>
                <li><a href="logout.php" style="color:white">Log Out</a></li>
                <?php } else { ?>
                <li><a href="login.php" style="color: white">Login</a></li>
                <li><a href="register.php" style="color: white">Sign Up</a></li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 well">
            <form role="form" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>" method="post" name="signupform">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>UPDATE Information</legend>

                    <input type=hidden value=Member name=mtype />
                    <CENTER><label>USER ID:</label>
                    <input type="hidden" value="<?php $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?>" name="id" disabled></CENTER>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_name'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($name_error)) echo $name_error; ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Email</label>
                        <input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_email'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($email_error)) echo $email_error; ?></span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Password</label>
                        To change your password, please contact the administrator.
                        <!--<span class="text-danger"><?php //if (isset($password_error)) echo $password_error; ?></span>!-->
                    </div>
                    <!--
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Confirm Password</label>
                        <input type="password" name="cpassword" placeholder="Confirm Password" class="form-control" />
                        <span class="text-danger"><?php //if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span>
                    </div>
                    !-->
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Date of Birth </label>
                        <input width=350px type="date" name="dob" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_dob'] ?>" class="form-control" pattern="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}" style="display:inline-block;width:350px!important"/><span class=validity></span>
                        <!-- span class="text-danger"><?php //if (isset($cpassword_error)) echo $cpassword_error; ?></span> !-->
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Gender</label>
                        <select name="gendr">
                            <option>Female</option>
                            <option>Male</option>
                            <option>Other</option>
                        </select>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Facebook Handle(please place only what comes after https://facebook.com/)<br />(Do not include the https://facebook.com part of the name)</label>
                        <input type="text" name="fbcdn" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_fbcdn'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Phone Number</label>
                        <input type="tel" name="phone" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_phone'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="adrs" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_adrs'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                        <input type="text" name="adrs_line" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_adrs_line'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">City</label>
                        <input type="text" name="city" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_city'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Province/State/Territory</label>
                        <input type="text" name="province" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_prov'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Postal/ZIP Code</label>
                        <input type="text" name="zip" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_zip'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="name">Country</label>
                            <input type="text" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_country'] ?>" class="form-control" />
                            <select name="country" id="country">
                                <option value="0" label="Select a country... " selected="selected">Select a country ...       </option>
                                    <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Africa" label="Africa">
                                        <option value="DZ" label="Algeria">Algeria</option>
                                        <option value="AO" label="Angola">Angola</option>
                                        <option value="BJ" label="Benin">Benin</option>
                                        <option value="BW" label="Botswana">Botswana</option>
                                        <option value="BF" label="Burkina Faso">Burkina Faso</option>
                                        <option value="BI" label="Burundi">Burundi</option>
                                        <option value="CM" label="Cameroon">Cameroon</option>
                                        <option value="CV" label="Cape Verde">Cape Verde</option>
                                        <option value="CF" label="Central African Republic">Central African Republic</option>
                                        <option value="TD" label="Chad">Chad</option>
                                        <option value="KM" label="Comoros">Comoros</option>
                                        <option value="CG" label="Congo - Brazzaville">Congo - Brazzaville</option>
                                        <option value="CD" label="Congo - Kinshasa">Congo - Kinshasa</option>
                                        <option value="CI" label="C&ocirc;te d'Ivoire">C&ocirc;te d'Ivoire</option>
                                        <option value="DJ" label="Djibouti">Djibouti</option>
                                        <option value="EG" label="Egypt">Egypt</option>
                                        <option value="GQ" label="Equatorial Guinea">Equatorial Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="ER" label="Eritrea">Eritrea</option>
                                        <option value="ET" label="Ethiopia">Ethiopia</option>
                                        <option value="GA" label="Gabon">Gabon</option>
                                        <option value="GM" label="Gambia">Gambia</option>
                                        <option value="GH" label="Ghana">Ghana</option>
                                        <option value="GN" label="Guinea">Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="GW" label="Guinea-Bissau">Guinea-Bissau</option>
                                        <option value="KE" label="Kenya">Kenya</option>
                                        <option value="LS" label="Lesotho">Lesotho</option>
                                        <option value="LR" label="Liberia">Liberia</option>
                                        <option value="LY" label="Libya">Libya</option>
                                        <option value="MG" label="Madagascar">Madagascar</option>
                                        <option value="MW" label="Malawi">Malawi</option>
                                        <option value="ML" label="Mali">Mali</option>
                                        <option value="MR" label="Mauritania">Mauritania</option>
                                        <option value="MU" label="Mauritius">Mauritius</option>
                                        <option value="YT" label="Mayotte">Mayotte</option>
                                        <option value="MA" label="Morocco">Morocco</option>
                                        <option value="MZ" label="Mozambique">Mozambique</option>
                                        <option value="NA" label="Namibia">Namibia</option>
                                        <option value="NE" label="Niger">Niger</option>
                                        <option value="NG" label="Nigeria">Nigeria</option>
                                        <option value="RW" label="Rwanda">Rwanda</option>
                                        <option value="RE" label="R&eacute;union">R&eacute;union</option>
                                        <option value="SH" label="Saint Helena">Saint Helena</option>
                                        <option value="SN" label="Senegal">Senegal</option>
                                        <option value="SC" label="Seychelles">Seychelles</option>
                                        <option value="SL" label="Sierra Leone">Sierra Leone</option>
                                        <option value="SO" label="Somalia">Somalia</option>
                                        <option value="ZA" label="South Africa">South Africa</option>
                                        <option value="SD" label="Sudan">Sudan</option>
                                        <option value="SZ" label="Swaziland">Swaziland</option>
                                        <option value="ST" label="S&atilde;o Tom&eacute; and Pr&iacute;ncipe">S&atilde;o Tom&eacute; and Pr&iacute;ncipe</option>
                                        <option value="TZ" label="Tanzania">Tanzania</option>
                                        <option value="TG" label="Togo">Togo</option>
                                        <option value="TN" label="Tunisia">Tunisia</option>
                                        <option value="UG" label="Uganda">Uganda</option>
                                        <option value="EH" label="Western Sahara">Western Sahara</option>
                                        <option value="ZM" label="Zambia">Zambia</option>
                                        <option value="ZW" label="Zimbabwe">Zimbabwe</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Americas" label="Americas">
                                        <option value="AI" label="Anguilla">Anguilla</option>
                                        <option value="AG" label="Antigua and Barbuda">Antigua and Barbuda</option>
                                        <option value="AR" label="Argentina">Argentina</option>
                                        <option value="AW" label="Aruba">Aruba</option>
                                        <option value="BS" label="Bahamas">Bahamas</option>
                                        <option value="BB" label="Barbados">Barbados</option>
                                        <option value="BZ" label="Belize">Belize</option>
                                        <option value="BM" label="Bermuda">Bermuda</option>
                                        <option value="BO" label="Bolivia">Bolivia</option>
                                        <option value="BR" label="Brazil">Brazil</option>
                                        <option value="VG" label="British Virgin Islands">British Virgin Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CA" label="Canada">Canada</option>
                                        <option value="KY" label="Cayman Islands">Cayman Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CL" label="Chile">Chile</option>
                                        <option value="CO" label="Colombia">Colombia</option>
                                        <option value="CR" label="Costa Rica">Costa Rica</option>
                                        <option value="CU" label="Cuba">Cuba</option>
                                        <option value="DM" label="Dominica">Dominica</option>
                                        <option value="DO" label="Dominican Republic">Dominican Republic</option>
                                        <option value="EC" label="Ecuador">Ecuador</option>
                                        <option value="SV" label="El Salvador">El Salvador</option>
                                        <option value="FK" label="Falkland Islands">Falkland Islands</option>
                                        <option value="GF" label="French Guiana">French Guiana</option>
                                        <option value="GL" label="Greenland">Greenland</option>
                                        <option value="GD" label="Grenada">Grenada</option>
                                        <option value="GP" label="Guadeloupe">Guadeloupe</option>
                                        <option value="GT" label="Guatemala">Guatemala</option>
                                        <option value="GY" label="Guyana">Guyana</option>
                                        <option value="HT" label="Haiti">Haiti</option>
                                        <option value="HN" label="Honduras">Honduras</option>
                                        <option value="JM" label="Jamaica">Jamaica</option>
                                        <option value="MQ" label="Martinique">Martinique</option>
                                        <option value="MX" label="Mexico">Mexico</option>
                                        <option value="MS" label="Montserrat">Montserrat</option>
                                        <option value="AN" label="Netherlands Antilles">Netherlands Antilles</option>
                                        <option value="NI" label="Nicaragua">Nicaragua</option>
                                        <option value="PA" label="Panama">Panama</option>
                                        <option value="PY" label="Paraguay">Paraguay</option>
                                        <option value="PE" label="Peru">Peru</option>
                                        <option value="PR" label="Puerto Rico">Puerto Rico</option>
                                        <option value="BL" label="Saint Barth&eacute;lemy">Saint Barth&eacute;lemy</option>
                                        <option value="KN" label="Saint Kitts and Nevis">Saint Kitts and Nevis</option>
                                        <option value="LC" label="Saint Lucia">Saint Lucia</option>
                                        <option value="MF" label="Saint Martin">Saint Martin</option>
                                        <option value="PM" label="Saint Pierre and Miquelon">Saint Pierre and Miquelon</option>
                                        <option value="VC" label="Saint Vincent and the Grenadines">Saint Vincent and the Grenadines</option>
                                        <option value="SR" label="Suriname">Suriname</option>
                                        <option value="TT" label="Trinidad and Tobago">Trinidad and Tobago</option>
                                        <option value="TC" label="Turks and Caicos Islands">Turks and Caicos Islands</option>
                                        <option value="VI" label="U.S. Virgin Islands">U.S. Virgin Islands</option>
                                        <option value="US" label="United States">United States</option>
                                        <option value="UY" label="Uruguay">Uruguay</option>
                                        <option value="VE" label="Venezuela">Venezuela</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Asia" label="Asia">
                                        <option value="AF" label="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
                                        <option value="AM" label="Armenia">Armenia</option>
                                        <option value="AZ" label="Azerbaijan">Azerbaijan</option>
                                        <option value="BH" label="Bahrain">Bahrain</option>
                                        <option value="BD" label="Bangladesh">Bangladesh</option>
                                        <option value="BT" label="Bhutan">Bhutan</option>
                                        <option value="BN" label="Brunei">Brunei</option>
                                        <option value="KH" label="Cambodia">Cambodia</option>
                                        <option value="CN" label="China">China</option>
                                        <option value="CY" label="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                                        <option value="GE" label="Georgia">Georgia</option>
                                        <option value="HK" label="Hong Kong SAR China">Hong Kong SAR China</option>
                                        <option value="IN" label="India">India</option>
                                        <option value="ID" label="Indonesia">Indonesia</option>
                                        <option value="IR" label="Iran">Iran</option>
                                        <option value="IQ" label="Iraq">Iraq</option>
                                        <option value="IL" label="Israel">Israel</option>
                                        <option value="JP" label="Japan">Japan</option>
                                        <option value="JO" label="Jordan">Jordan</option>
                                        <option value="KZ" label="Kazakhstan">Kazakhstan</option>
                                        <option value="KW" label="Kuwait">Kuwait</option>
                                        <option value="KG" label="Kyrgyzstan">Kyrgyzstan</option>
                                        <option value="LA" label="Laos">Laos</option>
                                        <option value="LB" label="Lebanon">Lebanon</option>
                                        <option value="MO" label="Macau SAR China">Macau SAR China</option>
                                        <option value="MY" label="Malaysia">Malaysia</option>
                                        <option value="MV" label="Maldives">Maldives</option>
                                        <option value="MN" label="Mongolia">Mongolia</option>
                                        <option value="MM" label="Myanmar [Burma]">Myanmar [Burma]</option>
                                        <option value="NP" label="Nepal">Nepal</option>
                                        <option value="NT" label="Neutral Zone">Neutral Zone</option>
                                        <option value="KP" label="North Korea">North Korea</option>
                                        <option value="OM" label="Oman">Oman</option>
                                        <option value="PK" label="Pakistan">Pakistan</option>
                                        <option value="PS" label="Palestinian Territories">Palestinian Territories</option>
                                        <option value="YD" label="People's Democratic Republic of Yemen">People's Democratic Republic of Yemen</option>
                                        <option value="PH" label="Philippines">Philippines</option>
                                        <option value="QA" label="Qatar">Qatar</option>
                                        <option value="SA" label="Saudi Arabia">Saudi Arabia</option>
                                        <option value="SG" label="Singapore">Singapore</option>
                                        <option value="KR" label="South Korea">South Korea</option>
                                        <option value="LK" label="Sri Lanka">Sri Lanka</option>
                                        <option value="SY" label="Syria">Syria</option>
                                        <option value="TW" label="Taiwan">Taiwan</option>
                                        <option value="TJ" label="Tajikistan">Tajikistan</option>
                                        <option value="TH" label="Thailand">Thailand</option>
                                        <option value="TL" label="Timor-Leste">Timor-Leste</option>
                                        <option value="TR" label="Turkey">Turkey</option>
                                        <option value="TM" label="Turkmenistan">Turkmenistan</option>
                                        <option value="AE" label="United Arab Emirates">United Arab Emirates</option>
                                        <option value="UZ" label="Uzbekistan">Uzbekistan</option>
                                        <option value="VN" label="Vietnam">Vietnam</option>
                                        <option value="YE" label="Yemen">Yemen</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Europe" label="Europe">
                                        <option value="AL" label="Albania">Albania</option>
                                        <option value="AD" label="Andorra">Andorra</option>
                                        <option value="AT" label="Austria">Austria</option>
                                        <option value="BY" label="Belarus">Belarus</option>
                                        <option value="BE" label="Belgium">Belgium</option>
                                        <option value="BA" label="Bosnia and Herzegovina">Bosnia and Herzegovina</option>
                                        <option value="BG" label="Bulgaria">Bulgaria</option>
                                        <option value="HR" label="Croatia">Croatia</option>
                                        <option value="CY" label="Cyprus">Cyprus</option>
                                        <option value="CZ" label="Czech Republic">Czech Republic</option>
                                        <option value="DK" label="Denmark">Denmark</option>
                                        <option value="DD" label="East Germany">East Germany</option>
                                        <option value="EE" label="Estonia">Estonia</option>
                                        <option value="FO" label="Faroe Islands">Faroe Islands</option>
                                        <option value="FI" label="Finland">Finland</option>
                                        <option value="FR" label="France">France</option>
                                        <option value="DE" label="Germany">Germany</option>
                                        <option value="GI" label="Gibraltar">Gibraltar</option>
                                        <option value="GR" label="Greece">Greece</option>
                                        <option value="GG" label="Guernsey">Guernsey</option>
                                        <option value="HU" label="Hungary">Hungary</option>
                                        <option value="IS" label="Iceland">Iceland</option>
                                        <option value="IE" label="Ireland">Ireland</option>
                                        <option value="IM" label="Isle of Man">Isle of Man</option>
                                        <option value="IT" label="Italy">Italy</option>
                                        <option value="JE" label="Jersey">Jersey</option>
                                        <option value="LV" label="Latvia">Latvia</option>
                                        <option value="LI" label="Liechtenstein">Liechtenstein</option>
                                        <option value="LT" label="Lithuania">Lithuania</option>
                                        <option value="LU" label="Luxembourg">Luxembourg</option>
                                        <option value="MK" label="Macedonia">Macedonia</option>
                                        <option value="MT" label="Malta">Malta</option>
                                        <option value="FX" label="Metropolitan France">Metropolitan France</option>
                                        <option value="MD" label="Moldova">Moldova</option>
                                        <option value="MC" label="Monaco">Monaco</option>
                                        <option value="ME" label="Montenegro">Montenegro</option>
                                        <option value="NL" label="Netherlands">Netherlands</option>
                                        <option value="NO" label="Norway">Norway</option>
                                        <option value="PL" label="Poland">Poland</option>
                                        <option value="PT" label="Portugal">Portugal</option>
                                        <option value="RO" label="Romania">Romania</option>
                                        <option value="RU" label="Russia">Russia</option>
                                        <option value="SM" label="San Marino">San Marino</option>
                                        <option value="RS" label="Serbia">Serbia</option>
                                        <option value="CS" label="Serbia and Montenegro">Serbia and Montenegro</option>
                                        <option value="SK" label="Slovakia">Slovakia</option>
                                        <option value="SI" label="Slovenia">Slovenia</option>
                                        <option value="ES" label="Spain">Spain</option>
                                        <option value="SJ" label="Svalbard and Jan Mayen">Svalbard and Jan Mayen</option>
                                        <option value="SE" label="Sweden">Sweden</option>
                                        <option value="CH" label="Switzerland">Switzerland</option>
                                        <option value="UA" label="Ukraine">Ukraine</option>
                                        <option value="SU" label="Union of Soviet Socialist Republics">Union of Soviet Socialist Republics</option>
                                        <option value="GB" label="United Kingdom">United Kingdom</option>
                                        <option value="VA" label="Vatican City">Vatican City</option>
                                        <option value="AX" label="&Aring;land Islands">&Aring;land Islands</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                    <optgroup id="country-optgroup-Oceania" label="Oceania">
                                        <option value="AS" label="American Samoa">American Samoa</option>
                                        <option value="AQ" label="Antarctica">Antarctica</option>
                                        <option value="AU" label="Australia">Australia</option>
                                        <option value="BV" label="Bouvet Island">Bouvet Island</option>
                                        <option value="IO" label="British Indian Ocean Territory">British Indian Ocean Territory</option>
                                        <option value="CX" label="Christmas Island">Christmas Island</option>
                                        <option value="CC" label="Cocos [Keeling] Islands">Cocos [Keeling] Islands</option>
                                        <option value="CK" label="Cook Islands">Cook Islands</option>
                                        <option value="FJ" label="Fiji">Fiji</option>
                                        <option value="PF" label="French Polynesia">French Polynesia</option>
                                        <option value="TF" label="French Southern Territories">French Southern Territories</option>
                                        <option value="GU" label="Guam">Guam</option>
                                        <option value="HM" label="Heard Island and McDonald Islands">Heard Island and McDonald Islands</option>
                                        <option value="KI" label="Kiribati">Kiribati</option>
                                        <option value="MH" label="Marshall Islands">Marshall Islands</option>
                                        <option value="FM" label="Micronesia">Micronesia</option>
                                        <option value="NR" label="Nauru">Nauru</option>
                                        <option value="NC" label="New Caledonia">New Caledonia</option>
                                        <option value="NZ" label="New Zealand">New Zealand</option>
                                        <option value="NU" label="Niue">Niue</option>
                                        <option value="NF" label="Norfolk Island">Norfolk Island</option>
                                        <option value="MP" label="Northern Mariana Islands">Northern Mariana Islands</option>
                                        <option value="PW" label="Palau">Palau</option>
                                        <option value="PG" label="Papua New Guinea">Papua New Guinea</option>
                                        <option value="PN" label="Pitcairn Islands">Pitcairn Islands</option>
                                        <option value="WS" label="Samoa">Samoa</option>
                                        <option value="SB" label="Solomon Islands">Solomon Islands</option>
                                        <option value="GS" label="South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands">South Georgia and the South Sandwich Islands</option>
                                        <option value="TK" label="Tokelau">Tokelau</option>
                                        <option value="TO" label="Tonga">Tonga</option>
                                        <option value="TV" label="Tuvalu">Tuvalu</option>
                                        <option value="UM" label="U.S. Minor Outlying Islands">U.S. Minor Outlying Islands</option>
                                        <option value="VU" label="Vanuatu">Vanuatu</option>
                                        <option value="WF" label="Wallis and Futuna">Wallis and Futuna</option>
                                    </optgroup>
                            </select>


                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <input type="submit" name="update" value="update" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
            <span class="text-success"><?php if (isset($successmsg)) { echo $successmsg; } ?></span>
            <span class="text-danger"><?php if (isset($errormsg)) { echo $errormsg; } ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4 text-center" style="color:white;"> 
        Already Registered? <a href="login.php">Login Here</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

What do I need to change to make this work properly?

Comment: Learn about prepared Statements to prevent SQL injection

Comment: Your script is at risk of [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
Use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: If you query by ID, `Limit 1`makes no sence. Because you only get one entry

Comment: You could also try looking for errors as they happen. Add `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('log_errors',1); error_reporting(E_ALL); mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);` to
the top of your script. This will force any `mysqli_` errors to
generate an Exception that you can see on the browser and other errors will also be visible on your browser.

Comment: Check for Errors after executing SQL statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to some change in your form 
1. do not use disabled in this case you can not get value

so update

```
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?>" name="id" disabled>
```

to

```
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?>" name="id">
```

and remove `mysqli_query($sql,$con);` line from php section because do not need to run it again so you can check query run successful using this

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "UPDATE users SET name='$name', accountType='$memberType', email='$email', address='$address', addresstwo='$addresstwo', city='$city', province='$province', country='$country', postal='$postal', phone='$phone', dob='$dob', gender='$gender', facebook='$facebook' WHERE id='$ident'");
if($result){
    echo "Updated data successfully\n";
}
```

hope it will help you

Answer (score 0):

You should not use a disabled field to pass your user ID, change this

```
<input type="number" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['usr_id']; ?>" name="id" disabled>
```

to this

```
<input type="hidden" value="<?= $_SESSION['usr_id'] ?>" name="id" />
```

You could also use the readonly property because elements with disabled property will not be submitted.

Also the LIMIT in your UPDATE query is useless

And as RiggsFolly suggested, you should use [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for security purpose.

Comment: Imade the changes like specified here however now i get a new error: `Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, boolean given in /home/zendasea/userAccounts/update.php on line 54`